# How to convert mathematica root expression to readable one?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, variable-definitions, variable

I am trying to find out at what regions a function is monotonically decreasing. The function is a function of X and has two more variables epsilon and B with the constrains 0 < B, 0 <epsilon< 1, epsilon< x <2*epsilon.
I tried Reduce, Solve, Roots, but I always get unreadable expressions, for example:
[image]

I will like some guidance, thanks

```
 Reduce[{-(((x - 2 ε) (120 ε^3 - 
       92 B ε^5 - 99 ε^6 - 
       20 x^2 ε (-27 + 20 B ε^2 + 
          21 ε^3) + 
       5 x^3 (-36 + 26 B ε^2 + 27 ε^3) + 
       x ε^2 (-480 + 364 B ε^2 + 
          387 ε^3)))/ε^5) < 0, 0 < B, 
  0 < ε < 1, ε < x < 2 ε, 
  x < 1}, {ε, B}]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to mathematica.SE. Then, please show us the code text rather than a screenshot of it, so we can easily test.

Comment: I edited the post with the code, thanks

Comment: use `//ToRadicals` and this wil attempt to replace each Root object with radical representation.

Comment: To be more specific, `ToRadicals` will help you transforming some of the `Root[…]`, but given that the solution involves root of 6th order polynomial `Root[60 x^3 - 180 x^2 #1 + 160 x #1^2 + (-40 - 45 x^3) #1^3 + 140 x^2 #1^4 - 129 x #1^5 + 33 #1^6 &, 1]`, I don't think it's possible to remove all the `Root[…]`.

Comment: Even when `ToRadicals` works, the result is usually less readable that the expression using `Root`. Radicals are a path to exploding complexity.

Comment: This will display the structure: ``With[{expr = Join[Union@Cases[sol, _Root, Infinity], Union@Cases[sol, t_Times /; LeafCount[t] > 15, Infinity]]},  With[{vars = Append[ Array[r, Length@expr - 1], B1[x, ε]]}, {sol /. Thread[expr -> vars], Thread[Inactive[Set][vars, expr]] } /. {s_, {set___}} :> Hold[Block[{r, B1}, set;  s]] // Activate] ]``

Comment: Oops, add this to my comment: "...where `sol` is the output of the OP's `Reduce[]` code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace the curlyEpsilon with e to make it easier to read.  Then the solution returned by Reduce is:

```
theSol=0 < x < 1 && ((x/2 < e < 
  Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 46 #1^3 &, 1] && 
 0 < B < (
  120 e^3 - 99 e^6 - 480 e^2 x + 387 e^5 x + 540 e x^2 - 
   420 e^4 x^2 - 180 x^3 + 135 e^3 x^3)/(
  92 e^5 - 364 e^4 x + 400 e^3 x^2 - 
   130 e^2 x^3)) || (Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 
     46 #1^3 &, 1] <= e <= 
  Root[60 x^3 - 180 x^2 #1 + 160 x #1^2 + (-40 - 45 x^3) #1^3 + 
     140 x^2 #1^4 - 129 x #1^5 + 33 #1^6 &, 1] && 
 B > 0) || (Root[
   60 x^3 - 180 x^2 #1 + 160 x #1^2 + (-40 - 45 x^3) #1^3 + 
     140 x^2 #1^4 - 129 x #1^5 + 33 #1^6 &, 1] < e < 
  Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 46 #1^3 &, 2] && 
 B > (120 e^3 - 99 e^6 - 480 e^2 x + 387 e^5 x + 540 e x^2 - 
   420 e^4 x^2 - 180 x^3 + 135 e^3 x^3)/(
  92 e^5 - 364 e^4 x + 400 e^3 x^2 - 130 e^2 x^3)))
```

and it's quite readable if you look at it as:

0<x<1 and (a and b or c or d).

Let's take the first part :  0<x<1 and (a and b) with:

**a: x/2 < e < Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 46 #1^3 &, 1]**

**b: 0 < B < (120 e^3 - 99 e^6 - 480 e^2 x + 387 e^5 x + 540 e x^2 -
420 e^4 x^2 - 180 x^3 + 135 e^3 x^3)/(
92 e^5 - 364 e^4 x + 400 e^3 x^2 - 130 e^2 x^3)**

First create a function for the root object of a:

```
f1[x_]:= Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 46 #1^3 &, 1]
```

and another for the polynomial of B:

```
f2[e_,x_]:=(120 e^3 - 99 e^6 - 480 e^2 x + 387 e^5 x + 540 e x^2 - 
  420 e^4 x^2 - 180 x^3 + 135 e^3 x^3)/(
 92 e^5 - 364 e^4 x + 400 e^3 x^2 - 130 e^2 x^3)
```

so that we can re-write the first relation as:

x<1 && (x/2<e<f1[x]) && (0<B<f2[e,x])

So let's check it:  Let x=0.5;

```
myX = 0.5;
f1[x_] := Root[-65 x^3 + 200 x^2 #1 - 182 x #1^2 + 46 #1^3 &, 1]
f1[myX]
myX/2
myE = 0.3;
f2[x_, e_] := (
  120 e^3 - 99 e^6 - 480 e^2 x + 387 e^5 x + 540 e x^2 - 
   420 e^4 x^2 - 180 x^3 + 135 e^3 x^3)/(
  92 e^5 - 364 e^4 x + 400 e^3 x^2 - 130 e^2 x^3);
f2[myX, myE]

(* 0.309958 *)

(* 0.25 *)

(* 27.1568 *)
```

so that we have x=0.5. and since (x/2<e<f1[x]) or 0.25<e<0.3099 so let e=0.3.  Then f2[0.5,0.3]=27.15.  So that 0<B<27.15 so let B=25.  Then substitute these values into the original expression:

```
myX = 0.5;
myE = 0.3;
myB = 25;
theF[x_, e_, 
  B_] := -(((-2 e + x) (120 e^3 - 92 B e^5 - 99 e^6 + 
     e^2 (-480 + 364 B e^2 + 387 e^3) x - 
     20 e (-27 + 20 B e^2 + 21 e^3) x^2 + 
     5 (-36 + 26 B e^2 + 27 e^3) x^3))/e^5)
theF[myX, myE, myB]

(* -1.1663 *)
```

which satisfies the relation.  And you can do the same for the rest.  It's a bit tedious but tractable in my opinion if you work with it.

**Note:**  I should point out it's not good Mathematica programming practice to use e as a user defined variable as it looks like the natural exponent which is E in Mathematica or [esc]ee[esc].  But I just used it here to keep consistent with your syntax.